# HTML form redirecting to a friendly URL

Tags: html, forms, url, post

Before I start off, I'd like to say that although there may be duplicate questions, I feel as if they were not descriptive enough and therefore did not help me resolve my issue. This is why I've decided to open a new question; please do not mark it as a duplicate.

Nevertheless, I'm building a profile-search page which allows people to search for a username within the database. It works fine, however, the HTML form redirects the user to the URL -

```
https://www.website.com/profile?p=USERNAME
```

instead of this way (the way I want it to)

```
https://www.website.com/profile/USERNAME
```

I tried using another way in PHP but it refreshes the page and I want the form to submit without it refreshing the page. The way I'm currently using works and does not refresh the page, but does not redirect to the right URL I want it to.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<form action="profile" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="search-user" />
</form>
```

Regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

What about using some Javascript to do an AJAX call instead then bringing the results back to a section in the page (a div or table output)

Something like http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form

Comment: Please include the actual code you're proposing to use in your answer. It helps to make the answer searchable for the purpose of future questions

Comment: No, because I want to allow users to also modify the URL themselves (https://www.website.com/profile/USERNAME). Instead of having to search, they could just replace USERNAME with whoever they want to search for. Has anyone got any other suggestions as to how I could get the HTML form to redirect to this type of link?